# how to use handler in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
  $(".productspecification").autocomplete({
          source: '/static/components/autocomplete/listspecification.ashx'
    });
```

> This is my handler

```
   public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    StringBuilder sbSpecs = new StringBuilder();
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/YKIOSK/static/components/autocomplete/specifications.txt"));
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        if (s.ToLower().Contains(context.Request.QueryString["term"].ToLower()))
        {
            result.Add(s); 
        } 
    }
    context.Response.Write(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result));
}
```

I want to add a webservices in place of the specifications.txt

Comment: where asp.net/asp.net MVC/java?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax to get data and then is success you need to create items for auto complete.

```
$("#productspecification").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "/static/components/autocomplete/listspecification.ashx",
             type: "GET",
             data: request,
             success: function (data) {
                 response($.map(data, function (el) {
                     return {
                         label: yourLabel,
                         value: Yourvalue
                     };
                 }));
             }
         });
    },
```

Then look for , how to access web service c#, asp.net.

```
//Use the Web Service that your Web server provides.
       localhost.Service1 MyService = new localhost.Service1();
       //Invoke the public WebMethod of the serice.
var webdata= MyService.MyMethod();
```

or using [web client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), [http client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
Using Client As New HttpClient()
Dim APIhostUri As String = “http://localhost:2025/&#8221;
Dim APIResponse As HttpResponseMessage
Client.BaseAddress = New Uri(APIhostUri)
```

Comment: how do i use webservice in the hadler insted of the given text file

Comment: Then look for , how to access web service c#, asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i think you should ditch the handler and call webservice from your script to get your autocomplete data like this

```
$("#productspecification").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "url to your web method",
         type: "GET",
         data: request,
         success: function (data) {
             response($.map(data, function (el) {
                 return {
                     label: yourLabel,
                     value: Yourvalue
                 };
             }));
         }
     });
},
```

if you still want to use handler then you need to plug in a webservice consumer module to get data from webservice and return as response.

Something like this.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
StringBuilder sbSpecs = new StringBuilder();
var wcfClient=new YourWcfProxy();
var term=context.Request.QueryString["term"];
string[] lines = wcfClient.GetLinesFor(term);
context.Response.Write(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result));
}
```

Comment: [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public List<Upload> Fetchspecification()
    {
        UploadBLL upb = new UploadBLL();
        DataTable dtbrand = upb.Fetchspecification();
        List<Upload> objbrand = new List<Upload>();
        if (dtbrand.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtbrand.Rows)
            {
                Uploaddtlbrand = new Upload();
                dtlbrand.specification = dr["Specification"].ToString();
                 objbrand.Add(dtlbrand);
            }

        }
        return objbrand;
    } this is my webservice

Comment: First of all may i point out that you should really try to name your objects and functions properly to make any sense.

Secondly your web method does not seem to take any input but you are looking to resolve some autocomplete data based on 'term' from this service. ideally your web service should take a parameter 'term' and return possible autocomplete words from what i understood from your question. if that is not true then i am completely puzzled